# Getting local language code from lat lon cordinates

Tags: locale, leaflet, wikipedia-api

I would like to use the current latlon centre of a Leaflet map to detect the local language so that I can choose which Wikipedia version to query against. Currently I am just querying the English version but that limits the results. For example in Tallin ...

English - 80 results - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=1000&gslimit=500&gscoord=59.436682840436205%7C24.747337102890015

Estonian - 109 results - https://et.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=1000&gslimit=500&gscoord=59.436682840436205%7C24.747337102890015

Also, the place names are returned in the local language, which is a good thing for me.

I appreciate that sometimes there may be ambiguity, and other times maybe I'll get a language that there isn't a Wikipedia for (list at http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias#All_Wikipedias_ordered_by_number_of_articles), but I can code for that and default to English as a fallback.

By way of background:

I have a prototype app at http://postcodepast.com which aims to allow discovery of cultural heritage content local to where people search (their home town for example). It allows them to confirm locations (i.e. to geotag them), possibly improve the accuracy, or simply reject it when there are false matches. All the crowdsourced data generated from this will be released as open data (currently a geoJSON feed).

The way it does this is to look up local landmarks from Wikipedia and then search for these names across cultural heritage providers like Europeana, DPLA and Flickr Commons. I could equally use other sources of landmarks (e.g. a list of geotagged WW1 battlefields) or other providers (with wider geographical coverage, or maybe specific content). Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I would suggest you work with Wikidata instead. Here is an API to ask for objects close to a coordinate: http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html It will give you a list of objects, you can then get the languages the Wikipedia articles are avalable in or just request the name from Wikidata directly.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that looks promising. But just to confirm, that will then return all articles irrespective of which language edition they were published in? I just tried a search like http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=around[625,52.205,0.119,0.05]&props=* and get four results, but no titles, no language identifiers etc.

Comment: Yes, providing that someone have gotten around and added the coordinates on wikidata already (there is many articles where this has not been done yet but there is plenty of people working on it). From the wdq API I would suggest you just get the identifiers. Then use these in a query to the official Wikidata API to get titles and languages identifiers. Example with your result: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q4823094%7CQ5025431%7CQ6770688%7CQ15265793&props=labels

Comment: That is very cool, thank you. Do you know if there are any limits (apart from url string length for the get request) on the number of ids that I can pass?

Comment: According to https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities you can only send 50 values in each request (unless you get bot status, and then you can send 500).

Comment: @Ainali I think you should post that as an answer.